# How to generate augmented types from V14 metadata generated with subwasm

Tags: polkadot-js, metadata, custom-types

The common way of generated type augmentation is by fetching the latest metadata from a running node with the following piece of code:

```js
await provider.connect()
await provider.isReady
const result = await provider.send('state_getMetadata')
```

The return type of the call seems to be an object with the following structure:

```json
{
  "result": <scale_and_hex_encoded_metadata>
}
```

On the resulting JSON file, some variation of the `ts-node --skip-project ../../node_modules/.bin/polkadot-types-from-defs` is to be run.

We want to expose the generated metadata for a built WASM using `subwasm`, with  `subwasm metadata --json <runtime_wasm>`, which generates metadata in the following format:

```json
{
  "V14": {
    "types": {...},
    "pallets": [...],
    "extrinsic": {...},
    "ty": 232
  }
}
```

What is the way to use this metadata format to generate the augmented types? Do we need to apply some sort of encoding on the data before calling the `polkadot-types-from-defs` script? If so, what is the process? The RPC node seems to be returning a `MagicNumber` which the script expects, and I could not find much information about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest release of subwasm contains a flag `--format=json+scale` which will return exactly the `{"result": "<scale and hex encoded metadata>"}` that is needed.